# React-Native StatusBar's hidden property not working properly in React-Native Modal component

Tags: react-native

I am using react-native's Modal component in there I am using react-native's StatusBar component. But when I set the value of hidden props to true it doesn't works properly but when i use this 
StatusBar component in another View component it works fine. Here are some screen-shot and my code example

[image: Background shows in status bar]

code example

```
      <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={false}
        visible={this.state.modalVisible}
        onRequestClose={() => this.setModalVisible(false)}
      >
        <StatusBar hidden={true} />
        <VideoPlayer />
      </Modal>
```

Comment: Can you share package.json?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to keep `StatusBar` component in the `View` that wraps the `Modal` component.
Hide the `StatusBar` component only when the `Modal` is visible.

In your `Modal`'s parent component,

```
render(){
   <View>
       <StatusBar hidden={this.state.isModalVisible}/>
       <Modal visible={this.state.isModalVisible}/>
           ...
       </Modal>
        ...
   </View>
}
```

The `isModalVisible` variable will hold the current state of both `Modal` and `StatusBar`